# Flutter Callback with return error setState() or markNeedsBuild called during build

Tags: flutter, callback

I use PopupMenuButton to edit the listView. For every action PopupMenuButton (remove item, add item, edit item in listView) trying to do Callback. For example, the simplest case is to delete

```
//_editorChannels - data with which I fill in the list
delete(dynamic val) {
 setState(() => _editorChannels.removeWhere((data) => data == val));
}
```

But since I pass the callback function `delete` to the widget, when I create it I get error setState() or markNeedsBuild called during build. If change and remove the `setState()`, then no error occurs, but of course the list will not be updated when the item is deleted via callback.

```
delete(dynamic val) {
  _editorChannels.removeWhere((data) => data == val);
}
```

My PopupMenuButton Widget

```
  class PopMenuWidget2 extends StatelessWidget {
  final VoidCallback onDelete;

  const PopMenuWidget2({Key key, this.onDelete}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => PopupMenuButton<int>(
    onSelected: (result) {
      //On View
      if (result == 0) {}
      //On Edit
      if (result == 1) { }

      //OnDelete Callback run
      if (result == 2) {
        onDelete();
      }
    },
    itemBuilder: (context) => [
      PopupMenuItem(
        value: 0,
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Icon(
              Icons.remove_red_eye_rounded,
              color: Colors.black38,
            ),
            Text('  View Option', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black38)),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      PopupMenuItem(
        value: 1,
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Icon(
              Icons.create,
              color: Colors.black38,
            ),
            Text('  Edit Option', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black38)),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      PopupMenuItem(
        value: 2,
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Icon(
              Icons.delete,
              color: Colors.black38,
            ),
            Text('  Delete Option',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black38)),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ],
  );
 }
```

Main Widget

```
  class EditorPage extends StatefulWidget {

  EditorPage({Key key, this.Channels}) : super(key: key);

  final List<Channel> Channels;

  static const String routeName = "/EditorPage";

  @override
  _EditorPageState createState() => new _EditorPageState();
  }

  class _EditorPageState extends State<EditorPage> {
  Stream<Mock> _result;
  final _coreObj = new Core();

 List<Channel> _editorChannels;


  //callback onDelete
  delete(dynamic val) {
  setState(() => _editorChannels.removeWhere((data) => data == val));
 }

 @override
 void initState() {
 _editorChannels = widget.Channels;
 super.initState();
 }


@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return DefaultTabController(
    length: 2,
    child: new Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(''),
          bottom: TabBar(tabs: [
            Tab(icon: FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.calendarCheck), text: "One"),
            Tab(icon: FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.tasks), text: "Two"),
          ]),
        ),
        body: SafeArea(
            child: TabBarView(children: [
          Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Scaffold(
                  body: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: _editorChannels == null
                          ? 0
                          : _editorChannels.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        final item = _editorChannels[index];
                        return Card(
                          shadowColor: Colors.black26,
                          margin: EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
                          clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2),
                          ),
                          child: ListTile(
                              title: Container(
                                  child: Text(
                                item.Name != null ? item.Name : '',
                                style: new TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    fontSize: 16.0),
                              )),
                              subtitle: Text(item.Url),
                              onTap: () => {},
                              isThreeLine: false,
                              leading: getIconbyId(item.Status),
                              
                              

                               //Pass callback   
                              trailing: PopMenuWidget2(
                                onDelete: delete(item),
                              )),


                        );
                      }),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ]))));
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `setState()` to work you need to have `PopMenuWidget2` as `StatefulWidget` . Change

```
class PopMenuWidget2 extends StatelessWidget {
```

to

```
class PopMenuWidget2 extends StatefulWidget {
```

Also
Pass you callback function like link on it, not like result of function execution
`onDelete: () => onDelete(item)`

```
  trailing: PopMenuWidget(
  onDelete: () => onDelete(item),
  )),
```

**Full Code:**

```
class PopMenuWidget2 extends StatefulWidget {
  final VoidCallback onDelete;

  const PopMenuWidget2({Key key, this.onDelete}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _PopMenuWidget2State createState() => _PopMenuWidget2State();
}

class _PopMenuWidget2State extends State<PopMenuWidget2> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => PopupMenuButton<int>(
    onSelected: (result) {
      //On View
      if (result == 0) {}
      //On Edit
      if (result == 1) { }

      //OnDelete Callback run
      if (result == 2) {
        onDelete();
      }
    },
    itemBuilder: (context) => [
      PopupMenuItem(
        value: 0,
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Icon(
              Icons.remove_red_eye_rounded,
              color: Colors.black38,
            ),
            Text('  View Option', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black38)),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      PopupMenuItem(
        value: 1,
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Icon(
              Icons.create,
              color: Colors.black38,
            ),
            Text('  Edit Option', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black38)),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      PopupMenuItem(
        value: 2,
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Icon(
              Icons.delete,
              color: Colors.black38,
            ),
            Text('  Delete Option',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black38)),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ],
  );
}
```

Comment: thanks for solution, but setState () affects the state of only the widget in which it is called . In this case, PopMenuWidget2, even if there is a StatefulWidget, the situation will not change, because setState () is called on another place  EditorPage. There problem in  `onDelete: delete(item)`

Comment: I had a StatefulWidget first. Then I made PopMenuWidget2 for testing. Here is my first option, but the results are the same. https://gist.github.com/kvadrakot/f5fe0e3ee2d776303c077216dea61198

Comment: @АлександрИнженер ```onDelete: delete(item)``` Try printing item ```print(item);```. Just to know what you are passing.. if it is index.. Then let me know..

Comment: print result = `"Instance of 'Channel'"`. This is correct snapshot data type of listView.  I don't understand why `onDelete: delete(item)` is automatically launched when the widget is created, and 2 times. I thought this method is called only on click, but it auto-starts and tries to change the state of a widget that has not yet been created.

Comment: ```delete(dynamic val) { _editorChannels.removeWhere((data) => data == val);
}``` change this to ```delete(dynamic val) {_editorChannels.remove(val);
}``` now try.. Because for ```removeWhere``` you need to provide key 
 as shown ```user.removeWhere((key, value) => key == "lastName");```

Comment: There is no problem with deletion. There's a `setState()` problem. `onDelete: delete (item)` auto fires when the widget is created. This is the problem.  If I remove the parameter `item` and call `delete` method like a property, then normal works. `onDelete: delete`  and call `delete() {  setState(() => print("TEST"));}` But i need pass parametr and call like function `onDelete: delete (item)`

Comment: It works.. but here it does nor know what to delete.. without the ```data.key```.. And ```data``` and ```data.key``` are not same. The ```data.key``` will be ```==``` to ```val``` but not ```data```. So try ```delete(dynamic val) {_editorChannels.remove(val); }```

Comment: i tried, the error is the same. My code with state  delete(dynamic val) {
      setState(() => _editorChannels.remove(val));
    }`

Comment: @АлександрИнженер ```//_editorChannels - data with which I fill in the list``` but where is data. In data base?

Comment: @АлександрИнженер ```//_editorChannels - data with which I fill in the list``` but where is data. Here ```delete(dynamic val) { _editorChannels.removeWhere((data) => data == val);``` then ```_editorChannels``` should be replaced with list name ```Channels``` because here it is getting replaced in the ```data with which I fill in the list``` not the actual list so.. change to ```delete(dynamic val) { Channels.remove(val);}```

Comment: Thanks! You very help me! I found problem. I pass not link on function, but result of execution. I add its to you answer.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `VoidCallback` you have to define custom type:

```dart
typedef MyCustomCallback<T> = void Function(T value);
```

and change **onDelete** definition to:

```dart
      final MyCustomCallback onDelete;
```

finally fix the callback invocation to:

```dart
      if (result == 2) {
        onDelete(value);
      }
      
      // ...

      trailing: PopMenuWidget2(
        onDelete: (item) => delete(item),
      )),
```